# How to use python pandas to return the row which the column contain # symbol?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have table Car as below:

```
Car       Color 
Proton    White#Red
Perudua   Red
Proton    Black
Honda     Silver#Brown#Black
```

My expected output is filter and remain the row which the Color column contain "#" symbol only as below:

Expected ouput:

```
Car       Color 
Proton    White#Red
Honda     Silver#Brown#Black
```

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the column string methods using accessor `.str` then `contains` method for conditionally filtering:

```
df[df.Color.str.contains('#')]

    Car Color
0   Proton  White#Red
3   Honda   Silver#Brown#Black
```